# How to connect to MS Access 2007, from Java on a mac

Tags: java, jdbc, ms-access-2007, jndi

I'm looking for a way to connect to a MS Access 2007 database from Java. I don't believe the ODBC way is available to me as I'm writing on a mac and will be pushing this product to Linux. The HXTT drivers also do not work with 2007.

Is there a way, a tutorial, an example, etc that accomplishes this?
Setting the connection as a JNDI Datasource is preferable but not required

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [jackcess](http://jackcess.sourceforge.net/). I have not tried it (yet) myself, but it's a 100% pure java solution, no need for specific JDBC-like drivers

Answer (score 0):

I don't know much about Mac and ODBC relationship, but in Java database world you have 4 types of drivers (http://java.sun.com/products/jdbc/driverdesc.html), JDBC-ODBC bridge being the "first type".

If you'd go to the official Sun/Oracle page (http://developers.sun.com/product/jdbc/drivers) and search for second, third and fourth driver types for MS Access, you should get a list of results with links to each product.